# How to work with Model and Form in a REST api?

Tags: forms, api, rest, serialization, symfony

I'm wondering what is the best way to POST/PUT/PATCH entity or collection of entity within a REST api and using Symfony2.

I'd like to be able to accept json (and maybe xml) as input request, I know it is already possible to do that with Form, but I'm not sure it is the way to do.

Any advices?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using forms seems to be the best solution. This is what the forms are for.

Look into the [FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle), it'll save you some time.

Comment: I'm not sure why form are forms such use case, data are not modeled the same within a REST API. By the way I know the RestBundle but it doesn't provide any feature concerning these cases afaik.

Comment: To clearify a bit, I'm wondering if using forms is the best way to go against using the jms serializer bundle to deserialize the json object to a model I can work with.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. You can fetch an object from the db (or create a new one) and use forms to populate the object with submitted data (deserialized array). If you need to see examples, check out LiipHelloBundle: https://github.com/liip/LiipHelloBundle/blob/master/Controller/RestController.php